# how can I add Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel reference in Visual Studio 2013 community update 5

Tags: visual-studio-2013, excel-2007, excel-interop

In Visual Studio 2013 update 5, under reference manager **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel** reference is not provided, I installed Interop  manually but still it is not showing in reference manager.
I have Microsoft excel version 2007.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking at the right place? It should be here:
[image]

If it's not, check if components for MS Office development are installed in your visual studio.